# Can ἀνήρ refer to a woman?

Tags: greek, meaning

The name Alexander fairly transparently comes from *ἀλέξω* "defend" + *ἀνήρ* "man". As an epithet of Hera, I've heard it translated as "defender of *mankind*".

But I generally think of *ἀνήρ* as being specifically a male person, like *vir*, as opposed to *ἄνθρωπος*/*homo* "human".

Can *ἀνήρ* ever refer to a woman, or to humans regardless of gender?

Comment: Seems not: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0058%3Aentry%3Da)nh%2Fr

Comment: Whoever downvoted: suggestions for improvement?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *Androphagoi* (mentioned as cannibals in Herodotus book 4) would include men and women, and it beggars belief that they would only feast on males to the exclusion of women.

Acts 17.34 provides at least one good example of ἄνδρες being gender-neutral:

> τινὲς δὲ ἄνδρες κολληθέντες αὐτῷ ἐπίστευσαν, ἐν οἷς καὶ Διονύσιος ὁ Ἀρεοπαγίτης καὶ γυνὴ ὀνόματι Δάμαρις καὶ ἕτεροι σὺν αὐτοῖς.
>
> Some "men" followed him and believed, among whom was both Dionysius the Areopagite and a woman named Damaris, as well as others with them.

I'd also offer Euripides' *Orestes* 1523 as a good chance of doing so, too.

> Φρύξ: πᾶς ἀνήρ, κἂν δοῦλος ᾖ τις, ἥδεται τὸ φῶς ὁρῶν.
> Phrygian: Slave or free, every one is glad to gaze upon the light.

Throughout Greek poetry, Zeus is πατὴρ ἀνδρῶν τε θεῶν τε ("father of gods and men" e.g. in [Iliad 8.49](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0133%3Abook%3D8%3Acard%3D41)) — is Homer excluding women here? I highly doubt it.

That said, it's clear that the word primarily refers to males, and its derivatives have to do with male-ness.

I think part of the zealotry overlooks some of the interesting aspects of ancient languages. No one would deny that the plural *masculine* nominative ending of *Romanus* is *Romani*, yet a group of male and female Romans would still be *Romani*.

Comment: Excellent answer! Would you be interested in adding brief quotations from the cited sources, for reference? (I can look them up on Perseus later if you like.)

Comment: @Draconis Done.

Comment: It's worth noting that all these examples refer to people in general: *all men, every man, mankind,* etc. I'm doubtful we could find an example of *aner* in reference to a single specific woman or a group only of women.

Comment: @Anonym Agreed. No one could call eg Penelope an  ἀνήρ.

Comment: Also interesting to note: the Acts passage is translated as *viri*. Definitely jarring, at least to my ear.

Comment: @brianpck Jarring indeed. I think it says much about how in antiquity women were an afterthought.